# How to rotate a gltf model in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, gltf

Major noob over here. I'm trying to make this model rotate on it own and after trying answers from other posts I'm at a loss. My latest attempt gives me an error claiming that the reference is undefined. Please help.

The code I've been adapting is from a three.js example. I read that you could use something like `3dobject.rotation.x =+ 0.01` or `if (3dobject) 3dobject.rotation.x =+ 0.01` in the animate function but no luck. In this project I am defining `model = gltf.scene`  and then using `model.rotation.x =+ 0.01` in my animate function.

Anything helps thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>three.js webgl - glTF loader</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: Monospace;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #info {
        color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 100;
        display:block;
    }
    #info a {
        color: #75ddc1;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="info">
        <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> - GLTFLoader<br />
        Test fo 
        <a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">stuff</a><br />
    </div>
    
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    
    <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    
    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
    
    <div>
        <script>
        if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
        var container, stats;
        var controls
        var camera, scene, renderer, light;
        init();
        animate();
        function init() {
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.25, 20 );
            camera.position.set( -1.8, 0.9, 2.7 );
            
            
            
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
            controls.target.set( 0, -0.2, -0.2 );
            controls.update();
            
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            
            light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xbbbbff, 0x444422 );
            light.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
            scene.add( light );
            // model
            var model;
            var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            loader.load( 'models/gltf/Cube1.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
                gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
                    
                } );
                model = gltf.scene;
                scene.add( model );
                
            } );
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2 );
            renderer.gammaOutput = true;
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            // stats
            stats = new Stats();
            container.appendChild( stats.dom );
        }
        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }
        //
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            
            //****** this is where im trying to make it rotate
            
            model.rotation.x =+ 0.01;
            
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            stats.update();
            
        }
    </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code won't run in a Stack Overflow snippet, because it depends on other files referenced in the `<script/>` tags. If you're running it locally, what do you mean by "the reference is undefined"? What is the full error? But I think your mistake might just be this: add to a number using `+=`, not `=+`. The latter is the same as `x = (+0.1)` which just repeatedly sets X to the same value.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy  This is the error that shows up in the console:  untitled.html:103 Uncaught ReferenceError: model is not defined
    at animate (untitled.html:103)
animate @ untitled.html:103

Comment: line 103 is this:    model.rotation.x += 0.01;

Comment: You'll need to wait for the model to load before rotating it, try `if ( model) model.rotation.x += 0.01;`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Don's suggestions, I found one more issue - your **model is not defined globally, for it to be used in animate function**.

Add model along with other variables (global):

```
var camera, scene, renderer, light, model;
```

Then wait for model to actually load:

```
if (model) {
    model.rotation.x += 0.01;
}
```